# Ukrainian counterpart for "compliance" as a legal term?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Please advise the Ukrainian counterpart for **"compliance"** as a legal term, if any.

To the best of my awareness **"compliance"** itself or **"комплаєнс"**/**"комплаенс"** as alternatives are currently widely used.

E.g.

[Антикорупційний compliance](https://www.legalalliance.com.ua/ukr/antikorupcijnij-compliance-ta-dilova-etika/)

[Compliance-політика](http://journals.uran.ua/index.php/2079-4762/article/view/11563)

[Бізнес–комплаєнс, комплаєнс-ризики, комплаєнс-контроль](http://eztuir.ztu.edu.ua/handle/123456789/3214)

[Комплаенс-ризик, комплаенс-контроль](http://econom-ejournal.cdu.edu.ua/article/view/241)

Answer (score 6):

EU-Ukraine association treaty that has official legal texts in both English and Ukrainian, has the following translations:

[Article 62](http://eeas.europa.eu/archives/docs/ukraine/pdf/5_ua_title_iv_trade_and_trade-related_matters_en.pdf):
28. ... to determine if pests are present and/or to determine **compliance** with phytosanitary regulations;

[Стаття 62](http://www.kmu.gov.ua/kmu/docs/EA/00_Ukraine-EU_Association_Agreement_(body).pdf):
28. ...для  визначення  наявності  шкідників  та/або  визначення  **дотримання** фітосанітарних правил;

If the word "compliance" is used in a form "in compliance with something", також припустимо "відповідно до чогось":

[Article 396](http://eeas.europa.eu/archives/docs/ukraine/pdf/6_ua_title_v_economic_and_sector_cooperation_en.pdf):
2. ...so as to reinforce their independence, professionalism and links with other European media **in compliance with** European standards, including standards of the Council of Europe.

[Стаття 396](http://www.kmu.gov.ua/kmu/docs/EA/00_Ukraine-EU_Association_Agreement_(body).pdf):
2. ...з метою посилення їхньої незалежності, професіоналізму та зв’язків з іншими європейськими ЗМІ **відповідно до** європейських стандартів, зокрема стандартів Ради Європи.

Comment: many thanks for your good answer. RE Art. 396  *"in compliance with"* is a set phrase which indeed is translated as *"відповідно до/у відповідності до"*.  As for Art. 62, under this context  both  *"дотримання"* and *"відповідність"* are possible. Absolutely agree to the options under the AA (Association Agreement).

Comment: Much more compicated is the connotation as in the examples **"anti-corruption compliance"**, **"compliance policy"**, **"compliance risks"**, **"compliance control"**. Although **"відповідність"** seems the most appropriate, to my mind, in some cases (as **"business compliance"** - **"бізнес-відповідність"**, **"anti-corruption compliance"** - **"антикорупційна відповідність"**) it sounds a bit odd.

Answer (score 5):

Дотримання (узгодженого) стандарту, правил, закону, регламенту.

Приклади вжитку:

- ["дотримання законів"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%22&oq=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.4429j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
- ["дотримання стандартів"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%22&oq=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.4429j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22)

Щодо похідних термінів - деякі звучать нормально, деякі криво-косо:

- контроль за дотриманням Х
- політика щодо дотримання Х

Думаю що завжди вийде довше за "комплаєнс". Саме тому в бізнес і хайтек середовищах так розповсюджені кальки з англійської. Нічого не треба нікому пояснювати, комплаєнс - він усюди комплаєнс.

Comment: Дякую! Я теж в залежності від контексту перекладаю то як "дотримання", то як "відповідність". "Нічого не треба пояснювати" тим, хто "в темі". Але ж є ще люди й поза межами специфічних середовищ) Терміни мають бути зрозумілими, або ж принаймні повинно бути тлумачення в авторитетних джерелах, якщо їхнє вживання розповсюджується за межі закритих груп.

Answer (score -2):

догідливість, поступливість, погодливість, узгодженість?